# Analogic transformation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This might be a very trivial question: I apologize for it if it were the case.
Consider the following statement:

if a transformational relation exists between two forms A(x1) B(x1) which contain some subclass x1 of a class x, then given the same  form A(x2) of a similar subclass x2 of x, it is possible to obtain B(x2).

What kind of mathematical relation (here named analogic transformation) should hold for that statement to be true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m not sure I know what a “form” is in this context; and what kind of “similarity” do you have in mind?

Comment: for instance forms would be sentences of English and classes and subclasses would be made up of words.

Comment: Then I’m not sure that your question is amenable to mathematical treatment, where we like to have clear and unambiguous definitions that we can use for proving precise statements.